# Evaluate a chain of inequalities

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Write code to evaluate whether a chain of inequalities is true or false. An example input is the string

`3<=4!=9>3==3`

This is true because each of its components is true:

`(3<=4) and (4!=9) and (9>3) and (3==3)`

**Input:**

A string that represents a chain of one or more inequalities. The allowed comparison operators are

```
==   equals
!=   does not equal
>    is greater than
>=   is greater than or equal to
<    is less than
<=   is less than or equal to
```

The allowed numbers are single-digit numbers `0` through `9`. There won't be any spaces, parentheses, or other symbols.

**Output:**

The correctness of the inequality as a consistent [Truthy or Falsey](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2190/20260) value. Consistent means every Truthy output is the same and every Falsey output is the same.

**Restriction:**

The intent of this challenge is for you to write code that processes the inequalities, rather than have them be evaluating them as code, even for a single inequality in the chain. As such, methods like Python's `eval` and `exec` that evaluate or execute code are banned. So are functions which look up a method or operator given its name as a string. Nor is it allowed to launching processes or programs to do the evaluation for you.

**Test cases:**

```
3<=4!=9>3==3
True

3<=4!=4
False

5>5
False

8==8<9>0!=2>=1
True
```

Comment: Can we accept input with Unicode inequality signs like ≤ and ≥ instead of <= and >=?

Comment: @FUZxxl You can't.

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, 71 + 1 = 72

With command-line flag `-n`, run

```
p (0..99).none?{|i|~/#{a=i%10}(#{%w/!=|. <?=* >?=*/[a<=>b=i/10]})#{b}/}
```

Generates all possible failing regular expressions, and checks whether the input string matches any of them. Outputs `true` if none do, else `false`. Takes input via STDIN, separated by newlines.

Tricks:

- We get all possible pairs of digits by looping from 0 to 99 and extracting the 10s and 1s digits.
- The only actual comparison we do is `a<=>b`, which returns -1,0,or 1 for less than, equal to, or greater. These all slice to different elements of a three-string array, finding the regular expression for comparisons that don't match.

Comment: What a clever strategy!

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 82

```pl
$_=<>;($'<=>$&)-61+ord$1&&($2&&$&==$')^('$'lt$1)&&die"\n"while/\d(.)(=?)/g;print 1
```

Prints 1 when true and a blank line when false, since the empty string is Perl's main falsey value.

The while loop goes over the string matching the regex `\d(.)(=?)`. Then the variables `$1` and `$2` correspond to the characters of the operator, and the special variables `$&` and `$'` will behave as the two operands in a numerical context. The operands are compared with `<=>` and the result matched against the first character of the operator. Then equality and inequality is dealt with specially.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6) 110 <s>116</s>

Straightforward:scan string, c is current digit, l is last digit, o is operator.

```js
F=x=>(l='',[for(c of x)10-c?(v=!l||v&&(o<'<'?l!=c:(o[1]&&c==l)||(o<'='?l<c:o<'>'?c==l:l>c)),l=c,o=''):o+=c],v)
```

**Test** In Firefox / FireBug console

```js
;['3<=4!=9>3==3','3<=4!=4','5>5','8==8<9>0!=2>=1']
.forEach(s=>console.log(s,F(s)))
```

> 3<=4!=9>3==3 true
> 3<=4!=4 false
> 5>5 false
> 8==8<9>0!=2>=1 true

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 60 bytes

This code seems a bit ugly and potentially not fully optimized, but it's the best I've got so far.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q_A%2CsSer_S%25%40%40-(%5D)1%5C%40z%7B~%3AX%5C%3A%5Ei%5B'%3D%22)%3C%22P%22(%3E%22P'%3C'%5E'%3EPPP%5D%3D~e%26X%7D%2F%3B&input=8%3D%3D8%3C9%3E0!%3D2%3E%3D1)

```
q_A,sSer_S%@@-(])1\@z{~:X\:^i['=")<"P"(>"P'<'^'>PPP]=~e&X}/;
```

#### Explanation

```
q               "Read the input";
_A,sSer         "Copy the input and replace each digit with a space";
_S%             "Split around spaces to obtain the operation list";
@@-             "Remove operations from the input to obtain the operand list";
(])1\@z         "Remove the first operand from the list to be the initial left
                 operand, initialize the result to 1 (true), and pair up the
                 operations and remaining operands";
{               "For each operation-operand pair:";
  ~:X             "Let the operand be the right operand of this operation";
  \:^i            "Hash the operation (bitwise XOR of all characters)";
  [               "Begin cases:";
    '=              " 0: Equals";
    ")<"            " 1: Less than or equal to";
    P               " 2: (Invalid)";
    "(>"            " 3: Greater than or equal to";
    P               " 4: (Invalid)";
    '<              " 5: Less than";
    '^              " 6: Bitwise XOR (stand-in for not equal to)";
    '>              " 7: Greater than";
    P               " 8: (Invalid)";
    P               " 9: (Invalid)";
    P               "10: (Invalid)";
  ]=~             "Execute the case selected by the operation hash modulo 11";
  e&              "Compute the logical AND of the result and the value produced
                   by this operation to be the new result";
  X               "Let the right operand be the new left operand";
}/              "End for each";
;               "Clean up and implicitly print result";
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 156 bytes

```
r a=read[a]::Int
l"!"=(/=)
l"="=(==)
l">"=(>=)
l"<"=(<=)
k">"=(>)
k"<"=(<)
[]#_=1<2
(a:'=':b:c)#i=l[a]i(r b)&&c#r b
(a:b:c)#i=k[a]i(r b)&&c#r b
f(h:t)=t#r h
```

Usage example:

```
f "3<=4!=9>3==3"        -> True
f "3<=4!=4"             -> False
f "5>5"                 -> False
f "8==8<9>0!=2>=1"      -> True
```

Ungolfed version:

```
digitToInt d = read [d] :: Int

lookup2 "!" = (/=)
lookup2 "=" = (==)
lookup2 ">" = (>=)
lookup2 "<" = (<=)

lookup1 ">" = (>)
lookup1 "<" = (<)

eval []              _ = True
eval (op:'=':d:rest) i = lookup2 [op] i (digitToInt d) && eval rest (digitToInt d)
eval (op:d:rest)     i = lookup1 [op] i (digitToInt d) && eval rest (digitToInt d)

evalChain (hd:rest) = eval rest (digitToInt hd)
```

`eval` takes two arguments: the string to parse (starting always with a comparison operator) and a number `i` which is the left argument for comparison (and was the right argument in the previous round). The operator is returned by `lookup2` if it's a two character operator (check only 1st char, because 2nd is always `=`) and by `lookup1` if it's just a single character. `eval` calls itself recursively and combines all return values with logical and `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp - <del>300</del> <del>185</del>  <del>169</del> 165

```
(lambda(s)(loop for(a o b)on(mapcar'read-from-string(cdr(ppcre:split"([0-9]+)"s :with-registers-p t)))by #'cddr always(if o(funcall(case o(=='=)(!='/=)(t o))a b)t)))
```

## Example

```
(mapcar (lambda(s) ...)
       '("2<=3<=6>2<10!=3"
         "3<=4!=9>3==3" 
         "3<=4!=4" 
         "5>5"
         "8==8<9>0!=2>=1"))
=> (T T NIL NIL T)
```

## Explanation

```
(lambda (s)
  (loop for (a o b) on (mapcar
                        'read-from-string
                        (cdr
                         (cl-ppcre:split "([0-9]+)" s
                                         :with-registers-p t))) by #'cddr
        always (if o
                   (funcall (case o
                                  (== '=)
                                  (!= '/=)
                                  (t o))
                            a b)
                   t)))
```

- `ppcre:split` splits on digits; for example:

  ```
  (ppcre:split "([0-9]+)" "2<=3<=6>2<10!=3" :with-registers-p t)
  => ("" "2" "<=" "3" "<=" "6" ">" "2" "<" "10" "!=" "3")
  ```

  Notice the first empty string, which is discarded using `cdr`
- Mapping `read-from-string` to this list calls the `read` function for each strings, which returns symbols and numbers.
- `loop for (a op b) on '(3 < 5 > 2) by #'cddr` iterates over the list by a step of **2** and thus binds `a`, `op` and `b` as follows, for each successive pass.

  ```
  a  op  b
  ----------
  3  <    5
  5  >    2
  2  nil  nil
  ```
- `always` checks whether the next expression is always true: either the operator is `nil` (see above) or the result of the comparison holds (see below).
- the `case` selects a Common-Lisp comparison function, according to the symbol previously read; since some operators are identical in Lisp and the given language  we can simply return `o` in the default case.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>95</s> 102

```
t=1
n=o=3
for c in map(ord,raw_input()):
 o+=c
 if 47<c<58:t&=627>>(o-c+3*cmp(n,c))%13;n=c;o=0
print t
```

The loop is a straightforward pass through the string one character at a time. The `t&=...` part is where the magic happens. Basically, I hash the operator together with the value of `cmp(lhs,rhs)` (-1, 0, or 1 depending on if `lhs` is less, equal, or greater than `rhs`). The result is a key into a lookup table that gives 0 or 1 depending on whether the numbers compare properly given that operator.  What lookup table, you ask? It's the number 627 = `0001001110011` in binary.  Bitwise operators do the rest.

This works on the four given test cases; let me know if you find an error for another case.  I haven't tested it very rigorously.

Comment: You need to take in `a` as input.

Comment: @xnor Whoops. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 37 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
þS¡¦Uþü.S"=<!>"2×Sć«'<š'>ª3ôÀsèXδåÅ\P
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9vc2FiaWX//8O@U8KhwqZVw77DvC5TIj08IT4iMsOXU8SHwqsnPMWhJz7CqjPDtMOAc8OoWM60w6XDhVxQ//8zPD00IT05PjM9PTM) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l4Qn/D@8LPrTw0LLQw/sO79ELVrK1UbRTMjo8PfhI@6HV6jZHF6rbHVplfHjL4Ybiwysizm05vPRwa0zAf53/xja2Joq2lnbGtrbGXBCOCZepnSmXha2thY2lnYGirZGdrSEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
þ         # Only leave the digits of the (implicit) input-string
          #  i.e. "3<=4!=9>3==3" → "34933"
 S        # Convert it to a list of digits
          #  → [3,4,9,3,3]
  ¡       # Split the (implicit) input-string by those, to have a list of the comparisons
          #  → ["","<=","!=",">","==",""]
   ¦      # Remove the first item (which is an empty string)
          #  → ["<=","!=",">","==",""]
          # (it also contains a trailing empty string, but we'll ignore that)
    U     # Pop and store it in variable `X`
þ         # Only leave the digits of the (implicit) input-string again
 ü        # For each overlapping pair of digits:
  .S      #  Compare them: -1 if a<b; 0 if a==b; 1 if a>b
          #   → [[3,4],[4,9],[9,3],[3,3]] → [-1,-1,1,0]
"=<!>"    # Push string "=<!>"
      2×  # Double it to "=<!>=<!>"
        S # Convert it to a list of characters: ["=","<","!",">","=","<","!",">"]
ć         # Extract the head: pop and push remainder-list and head separately
 «        # Append this "=" to each: ["<=","!=",">=","==","<=","!=",">="]
  '<š'>ª  # Prepend a "<" and append a ">": ["<","<=","!=",">=","==","<=","!=",">=",">"]
3ô        # Split it into parts of size 3: [["<","<=","!="],[">=","==","<="],["!=",">=",">"]]
  À       # Rotate this list once left: [[">=","==","<="],["!=",">=",">"],["<","<=","!="]]
   sè     # Index the digit-comparisons into it (where the -1 indexes into the last item)
          #  → [["<","<=","!="],["<","<=","!="],["!=",">=",">"],[">=","==","<="]]
X         # Push the input-comparisons from variable `X` again
 δ        # Apply double-vectorized:
  å       #  Check if the current comparison is in the current list
          #   → [[1,1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0]]
   Å\     # Leave the main diagonal of these double-vectorized checks
          #  → [1,1,1,1]
     P    # And check if all are truthy by taking their product
          #  → 1
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 101 bytes

a different approach from the js solution posted here

```js
F=(s,i=0,l=o="")=>[...s].every(c=>c>=0?[l^c,l==c,,l<c,l>c,l<=c,,l>=c]["!==<><=>=".search(o,l=c,o="")]:o+=c,l=o="")

console.log(F("3<=4!=9>3==3")==true)
console.log(F("3<=4!=4")==false)
console.log(F("5>5")==false)
console.log(F("8==8<9>0!=2>=1")==true)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>283</s> 270 bytes

```java
s->{String[]a=s.split("\\d"),b=s.split("\\D+");int i=0,r=1,x,y;for(;i<a.length-1;y=new Byte(b[++i]),r-=a[i].equals("==")&x!=y|a[i].equals("!=")&x==y|a[i].equals(">")&x<=y|a[i].equals(">=")&x<y|a[i].equals("<")&x>=y|a[i].equals("<=")&x>y?1:0)x=new Byte(b[i]);return r>0;}
```

-13 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hZBBb4IwFIDv/ooHhwUiEJia6MrrkmXXefGoHgpWV4eF0eIkjt/OKrrEuYNJe@j3vqQv35btmZ8XXG5XH22aMaXgjQl57AEIqXm5ZimH6ekJkOR5xpmE1JnpUsgNKJeYQWOuOUozLVKYggSEVvn0eLbmS4YqUEUmtGMvFivb9ZJr8Nq3XWL@AoGhV2LkHbyarPPSISJmQcblRr/7EalR8i94qTV3knm/L5auV/rI5mIZ8M@KZcqxEW334WBh/f0HWx3GW0xPNP5HOzm@ofEJ0ls37lxaP0dPoXu43s9sR0quq1JCSUPStOTcqKiSzDS6pNrnYgU7U9v5LQXMPaee1UrzXZBXOijMSGfSkUHq2IMYhxZO6ABxYLtd/nvy8K43oqO7zhhxHE9oaOEjxeiiN72m/QE)

```java
s->{                             // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  String[]a=s.split("\\d"),      //  All the inequalities
          b=s.split("\\D+");     //  All the digits
  int i=0,                       //  Index-integer (starting at 0)
      r=1,                       //  Flag integer for the result, starting at 1
      x,y;                       //  Temp integer `x` and `y`
  for(;i<a.length-1              //  Loop `i` in the range [0, length]:
      ;                          //    After every iteration:
       y=new Byte(b[++i]),       //     Convert the `i+1`'th digit from String to integer,
                                 //     and store it in `y`
       r-=                       //     Decrease the result by:
          a[i].equals("==")&x!=y //      If "==" and `x` and `y` are not equal
          |a[i].equals("!=")&x==y//      or if "!=" and `x` and `y` are equal
          |a[i].equals(">")&x<=y //      or if ">" and `x` is smaller than or equal to `y`
          |a[i].equals(">=")&x<y //      or if ">=" and `x` is smaller than `y`
          |a[i].equals("<")&x>=y //      or if "<" and `x` is larger than o equal to `y`
          |a[i].equals("<=")&x>y //      or if "<=" and `x` is larger than `y`:
           1                     //       Decrease the result by 1
          :0;                    //      Else: keep it the same by decreasing with 0
    x=new Byte(b[i]);            //   Convert the `i`'th digit from String to integer,
                                 //   and store it in `x`
  return r>0;}                   //  Return whether the result is still 1
```