# Expand Comparison Chains

Tags: code-golf, parsing, conversion, syntax

Unlike most languages, Python evaluates `a<b<c` as it would be done in mathematics, actually comparing the three numbers, as opposed to comparing the boolean `a<b` to `c`. The correct way to write this in C (and many others) would be `a<b && b<c`.

In this challenge, your task is to expand such comparison chains of arbitrary lengths from the Python/intuitive representation, to how it would be written in other languages.

## Specifications

- Your program will have to handle the operators: `==, !=, <, >, <=, >=`.
- The input will have comparison chains using only integers.
- Don't worry about the trueness of any of the comparisons along the way, this is purely a parsing/syntactical challenge.
- The input won't have any whitespace to prevent answers that trivialize parsing by splitting on spaces.
- However, your output may have a single space surrounding either just the `&&`'s, or both the comparison operators and the `&&`'s, or neither, but be consistent.

## Test Cases

```
Input                  Output
---------------------------------------------------------------

3<4<5                  3<4 && 4<5
3<4<5<6<7<8<9          3<4 && 4<5 && 5<6 && 6<7 && 7<8 && 8<9
3<5==6<19              3<5 && 5==6 && 6<19
10>=5<7!=20            10>=5 && 5<7 && 7!=20
15==15==15==15==15     15==15 && 15==15 && 15==15 && 15==15
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47417/evaluate-a-chain-of-inequalities)

Comment: Can I have two spaces either side of the `&&`?

Comment: @H.PWiz nope, srry.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>33</s> <s>22</s> 17 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder*

```
-2`\D(\d+)
$&&&$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX9coIcZFIyZFW5NLRU1NTcXw/39jGxMbUy4waWNmY25jYWMJ5Jna2prZGFpyGRrY2ZramCvaGnEZAsVQMQA)

Comment: @MartinEnder A pity `1>-2` doesn't work to limit from both ends at once...

Comment: @Neil yeah, Retina 1.0 will get a new limit syntax where that's possible.

Comment: Could you post an explanation?

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

Prints a space around each operator.

```
wJ"&&"m←C2X3ġ±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v9xLSU1NKfdR2wRnowjjIwsPbfz//7@xjYmNqY2ZjbmNhY0lAA)

#### Explanation:

```
                  Implicit input, e.g            "3<4<5<6"
            ġ±    Group digits                   ["3","<","4","<","5","<","6"]
          X3      Sublists of length 3           [["3","<","4"],["<","4","<"],["4","<","5"],["<","5","<"],["5","<","6"]]
        C2        Cut into lists of length 2     [[["3","<","4"],["<","4","<"]],[["4","<","5"],["<","5","<"]],[["5","<","6"]]]
      m←          Take the first element of each [["3","<","4"],["4","<","5"],["5","<","6"]]
 J"&&"            Join with "&&"                 ["3","<","4","&&","4","<","5","&&","5","<","6"]
w                 Print, separates by spaces
```

Comment: Nice one. You could use `w` instead of `;` for a more direct approach to joining strings with spaces

Comment: Oh yes, how didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>42</s> <s>47</s> 22 bytes

Massively golfed thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```
(\D(\d+))(?=\D)
$1&&$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fI8ZFIyZFW1NTw942xkWTS8VQTU3F6P9/QwM7W1Mbc0VbIwA)

Comment: `(==|!=|<=?|>=?)` can be  `\D+`

Comment: Similarly `(?<!^|\d)` can be `(?<=\D)`. Also the `(?=\d+)` is unnecessary, the operator will always be followed by an operand, at which point you can drop the `+` after the `\D`. There's also `$&` instead of `$1$2`, and then a further byte can be saved by capturing behind and looking ahead instead of capturing ahead and looking behind.

Comment: `(\D(\d+))(?=\D)` on line 1, and `$1&&$2` on line two is enough (**22 bytes**). [Try it here.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fI8ZFIyZFW1NTw942xkWTS8VQTU3F6P9/QwM7W1Mbc0VbIwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 37 bytes

```
òÍ¨ä«„0-9& ]«©¨ä«©¨„0-9& ]«©/±² ¦¦ ²³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Cmw72HVhxecmj1oRYDXUs1hVggayVUBEgji@of2nhok8KhZYeWKRzadGjz///GNiY2plxg0sbMxtzGwsYSyDO1tTWzMbTkMjSwszW1MVe0NTLgMgQKomIA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: f2cd a8e4 ab84 302d 3926 205d aba9 a8e4  ......0-9& ]....
00000010: aba9 a884 302d 3926 205d aba9 2fb1 b220  ....0-9& ]../.. 
00000020: a6a6 20b2 b3                             .. ..
```

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 88 bytes

Update: `subs` instead of `clojure.string/join`.

```
#(subs(apply str(for[p(partition 3 2(re-seq #"(?:\d+|[^\d]+)" %))](apply str" && "p)))4)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>59</s> 46 bytes

```
4(}.;)_2{.\3' && '&;\]</.~0+/\@,2~:/\e.&'!<=>'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8FEo1bPWjPeqFovxlhdQU1NQV3NOibWRl@vzkBbP8ZBx6jOSj8mVU9NXdHG1k79f2pyRr5DmoOdQnJpiY@bQnFJSmaeuvp/YxsTG1MuMGljZmNuY2FjCeSZ2tqa2Rhachka2Nma2pgr2hoZcBkCBVExAA)

#### How it used to work

```
                        (0 , }. ~:&(e.&'!<=>') }:)
```

We’re looking for operator boundaries. “Beheaded” and “curtailed” strings are turned into zeroes and ones where 0s are digits, then xored together. Prepend zero to match the length.

```
                   +/\                      </. ]     Split on boundaries. 
              ┌──┬──┬─┬─┬─┬──┬──┐
              │10│>=│5│<│7│!=│20│
              └──┴──┴─┴─┴─┴──┴──┘
         3' && '&;\          Add && to infixes of 3.
              ┌────┬──┬──┬──┐
              │ && │10│>=│5 │
              ├────┼──┼──┼──┤
              │ && │>=│5 │< │
              ├────┼──┼──┼──┤
              │ && │5 │< │7 │
              ├────┼──┼──┼──┤
              │ && │< │7 │!=│
              ├────┼──┼──┼──┤
              │ && │7 │!=│20│
              └────┴──┴──┴──┘
    _2{.\                    Take even numbered rows.
;}.,                         Concatenate after dropping the first box.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Charcoal, 29 bytes

```
≔ ηＦθ«¿›ι9«Ｆ›η!⁺&&η≔ωη»≔⁺ηιηι
≔ ηＦθ«Ｆ∧›ι9›η!⁺&&η≔⎇›ι9ω⁺ηιηι
```

Two slightly different formulations of the same basic algorithm. The input string is iterated by character. As digits are found they are collected in a variable. When a boundary between a number and operator is found, an extra "&&" plus the variable is printed and the variable is cleared. The variable is initially initialised to a space so that the first boundary doesn't trigger the extra "&&".

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
e€ØDŒg⁸ṁṡ3m2j⁾&&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//ZeKCrMOYRMWSZ@KBuOG5geG5oTNtMmrigb4mJv///ycxMD49NTw3IT0yMCc)

Explanation:

```
e€ØDŒg⁸ṁṡ3m2j⁾&& Uses Jelly stringification, thus full program only
e€ØD             For each each char, 1 if it's in '0123456789', otherwise 0
    Œg           Split into longest runs of equal elements
      ⁸ṁ         Reshape original input like the list we just made
                 Reshaping will separate numbers from operators
        ṡ3       Get contiguous sublists of length 3
          m2     Keep every second item, starting from the first
                 This will keep every (number operator number) and
                 remove every (operator number operator) substring
            j⁾&& Join with '&&'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 46 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(\\D(\\d+))(?=\\D)","$1&&$2")
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jY5BawIxEIXv/oppEElQF9d2tWKiCF710mPtIc3GEo3ZZROFIvvb17HNxYsKeZCZ@ebN28mT7Beldrt83ygrvYeVNO7cAjAu6GorlYb1tQT4CJVxP6Bo/Hg2xX6NwueDDEbBGhwIaHx/5pNKlxbXF9ZSQjebJSrvMkbnAgtGeqSddjrtIWHN9N@jPH5b9IhWp8LkcMAw8d7nF0gWk/z6oA9JcQxJiaNgHXWJouSVvxH2l@ouw7PnKD7iY/7OJ0/QmRAjnj4m08FMZHz8IoaDxyya3iqu1K26uQA)

```java
s->                       // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
   s.replaceAll("(\\D(\\d+))(?=\\D)",
                "$1&&$2") //  Replace the match of the regex
                          //  with the second String
                          // End of method (implicit / single-line return-statement)
```

Regex explanation:

```
(\D(\d+))(?=\D)   # 1) For all matches of this regex
   (\d+)          #  Capture group 2: a number (one or more digits)
(\D \d+ )         #  Capture group 1: anything but a number + the number
                  #   (`\D` will match the `=`, `!`, `<`, or `>`)
         (?=\D)   #  Look-ahead so everything after the match remains as is
 
 $1&&$2           # 2) Replace it with
 $1               #  Result of capture group 1 (trailing part of the equation + the number)
   &&             #  Literal "&&"
     $2           #  Result of capture group 2 (the number)
```

Step by step example of the replacements:

```
Initial:                             10>=5<7!=20
 Match of first replacement:            =5
 Replace with:                          =5&&5
After first replacement:             10>=5&&5<7!=20
 Match of second replacement:                <7
 Replace with:                               <7&&7
After second replacement (result):   10>=5&&5<7&&7!=20
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 47 + 1 (-p) = 48 bytes

```perl
$\.=$1." && "x(!!$')while s/(\d+\D+(\d+))/$2/}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRs9WxVBPSUFNTUGpQkNRUUVdszwjMydVoVhfIyZFO8ZFG0RpauqrGOnXVv//b2hgZ2tqY65oa2TwL7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub(r'(\D(\d+))(?=\D)',r'\1&&\2',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcqxDoIwFIXhnaeoC7eNxNBqQc29uvAYXSBAJBFobuvg01fXDmf5zu@/8bVvJs3k0rtfh7EX4c7TKXwGySBdJ914VEo@yXUKKgany9IZqIIqltXvHAVPyfOyRTFLOOMFLagiB2ywxSve8sMSNagz1PWDLLYHMnXG/zQfqPQD)

Comment: `re.sub(r'\D(\d+)(?=\D)',r'\g<0>&&\1',s)` saves 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub(/\D(\d+)(?=\D)/,'\&&&\1')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvvbg0SUM/xkUjJkVbU8PeNsZFU19HPUZNTS3GUF2z9n9BaUmxQlq0urGNiY2peiwXCt/GzMbcxsLGEkXc1NbWzMYQWczQwM7W1MZc0dbIAFkUqBAVq8f@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 43 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>s.replace(/(\W+(\d+))(?!$)/g,"$1&&$2")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z/NttjWrlivKLUgJzE5VUNfIyZcWyMmRVtTU8NeUUVTP11HScVQTU3FSEnz/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
e€ØDnƝkṡ3m2j⁾&&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/1UdOawzNc8o7NzX64c6FxrlHWo8Z9amrYxBvmKKipKTxqmMt1uB0oG/n/fzQXp5KxjYmNqZKOAjpQVgDKgDQApWHKbMxszG0sbCyRlCMrA1FANSAKqBBEAVWDKKAWsBGmtrZmNoaWaLaBjIDoBUpDNBuC1Bsa2Nma2pgr2hoZoOhQVgDLQGyDWANSA9IBNAEVQzQCdYB5ILW4WVyxAA)

Outputs with no spaces around the `&&`, but the Footer in the TIO link adds the spaces to make the output easier to read

### How it works

```
e€ØDnƝkṡ3m2j⁾&& - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
e€ØD            - Replace digits with 1, otherwise 0
     Ɲ          - To overlapping pairs [a,b]:
    n           -   a ≠ b
      k         - Split S on truthy elements, grouping digits together
       ṡ3       - Split into overlapping lists of length 3
         m2     - Take every other element
           j⁾&& - Join by "&&"
```